# Oauth aware flow issue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth

Problem statement: calling methods on the oauth aware decorator causes a nonetype error.

I look at this page
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine

Specifically the code in the guide under:
In the following code snippet, the OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets class is used to create an oauth_aware decorator, and the decorator is applied to a function that accesses the Google Tasks API:

and try and create something similar (included below).

My app is giving this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/APPNAME/DIRECTORYNAME/main.py", line 39, in get
    url = decorator.authorize_url()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/APPNAME/DIRECTORYNAME/oauth2client/appengine.py", line 798, in authorize_url
    url = self.flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'step1_get_authorize_url'
```

When I do logging.info(decorator) it returns

and when I do

```
>>>logging.info(dir(decorator))
>>> ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_auth_uri', '_callback_path', '_client_id', '_client_secret', '_create_flow', '_credentials_class', '_credentials_property_name', '_display_error_message', '_in_error', '_kwargs', '_message', '_revoke_uri', '_scope', '_storage_class', '_tls', '_token_response_param', '_token_uri', '_user_agent', 'authorize_url', 'callback_application', 'callback_handler', 'callback_path', 'credentials', 'flow', 'get_credentials', 'get_flow', 'has_credentials', 'http', 'oauth_aware', 'oauth_required', 'set_credentials', 'set_flow']
```

but any of those methods like decorator.http() or decorator.has_credentials() triggers a none type error

My code

```
import webapp2
import logging
import jinja2
import pprint
import os
import json
import time
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run

from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

decorator = OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json'),
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')

# Google App Engine project ID
PROJECT_NUMBER = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2')

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if decorator.has_credentials():
            logging.info('has credentials')
        else:
            logging.info('bouncing credentials')
            logging.info(decorator)
            url = decorator.authorize_url()
            return self.redirect(url)

        jinja_environment = self.jinja_environment
        template = jinja_environment.get_template("/index.html")
        self.response.out.write(template.render())

    @property
    def jinja_environment(self):
        jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
            loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('views')

        )
        return jinja_environment

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    (decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler()),
    ], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From perusing the source, I think the "decorator" should be used to decorate something before you use it to do other things.  In this case, you probably want to decorate `get` with [`oauth_aware`](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/oauth2client/appengine.py#752):

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @decorator.oauth_aware
    def get(self):
        if decorator.has_credentials():
            ...
        else:
            ...
            url = decorator.authorize_url()
```